# Converter uma chamada form action para axios

Tags: javascript, axios

boa noite

estou tendo problemas em converter este codigo

```
<form action="https://www.personal.com.py/ApiComerciosMaven/webresources/autenticacion/" method="post">
      <p>
        AUTENTICAR USUARIO
      </P>
<p style="font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;">USUARIO
<input type="text" name="usuario" value="test">
</p>
<p style="font-size:medium;font-weight:bold;">CLAVE
<input type="text" name="clave" value="test">
</p>               
<p>
<input type="submit" value="AUTENTICAR"/>
</p>
</P>
</form>
```

para axios, tentei isso

```
    axios.post('https://www.personal.com.py/ApiComerciosMaven/webresources/autenticacion/', {usuario: 'AA', clave: 'AA'}).then(req => {
  console.log('Req done: ', req)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Error: ', err)
})
```

e assim

```
    const data = new FormData();
data.append('usuario', 'AA');
data.append('clave', 'AA');


axios.post('https://www.personal.com.py/ApiComerciosMaven/webresources/autenticacion/', data).then(req => {
  console.log('Req done: ', req)
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Error: ', err)
})
```

porem a requisicão com o html me retorna o data esperado porem com o axios não, como poderia converter esse html em uma requisicão axios?

desde já obrigado

Comment: Tente enviar via get com params: `axios.get('https://www.personal.com.py/ApiComerciosMaven/webresources/autenticacion/', { params: {usuario: 'AA', clave: 'AA'}}).then(`

Answer (score 0):

bom dia,
se eu usar o get ele me retorna um erro 404, tem que ser post mesmo, ao usar post pelo axios ele realiza a requisição com sucesso, porem não me traz o mesmo resultado que fazendo pelo navegador.

Comment: Na dúvida você postou que tava problema no axios, e agora postou que está com problema no HTML. Os retornos diferem?

Comment: a requisicão no html funciona, o que eu não consigo é fazer o mesmo com o axios, tentei usar o fetch, porem ele me retorna o mesmo resultado que o axios

Comment: O que ele retorna lá no console.log?

Comment: no axios: codigo: 0, mensaje: ""
no html: codigo:0, mensaje: "asdsada87d89a7d9as7das98d7as9" <= token

Comment: O axios ele faz um pre requisição chamado pre flight, eu não sei se isso tem influência. Já tentou realize um teste com o ajax do jQuery.

Comment: vou fazer uns testes com ajax, porem não deveria interferir teoricamente

Answer (score 0):

> O axios ele faz um pre requisição chamado pre flight, eu não sei se isso >tem influência. Já tentou realize um teste com o ajax do jQuery.

muito obrigado richellyitalo

Solução

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Seta tipo de requisição: Post e a URL da API
ajax.open("POST", "minha-url-api", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

// Seta paramêtros da requisição e envia a requisição
ajax.send("email=teste@teste.com");

// Cria um evento para receber o retorno.
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {

  // Caso o state seja 4 e o http.status for 200, é porque a requisiçõe deu certo.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {

        var data = ajax.responseText;

    // Retorno do Ajax
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```